# How to model intraday risk per customer using Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a dataset containing intraday gambling activity for each customer.
My goal is to implement an ML model to detect when the risk changes from normal to abnormal during the day for each customer.
The problem is not a supervised problem, so I would need to implement some strategy.
How can one tackle such a problem?

Comment: The question posits that a gambler can transition between 2 states (normal, abnormal) during a day. This seems amenable to [tag:hidden-markov-model]s and similar.

Comment: What constitutes normal, and what constitutes abnormal?